# Verification of poly1305-donna-16.h code

Tags: c, cryptography, pascal

The RFC from May 2015 Y. Nir et al, ChaCha20 and Poly1305 for IETF Protocols
(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) contains a reference to the MIT/Public domain C library https://github.com/floodyberry/poly1305-donna.

I am just porting the C code to Pascal. The 8 bit code works OK (self-test, example, and RFC test vectors).

The port from poly1305-donna-16.h using 16->32 bit multiples and 32 bit additions failed. After some testing I compiled the original source with DJGPP GCC 4.7.3, MS VC 6.0 and BC 3.1 and all three failed too (poly1305 self-test).

**Questions**: Does this C version (build with -DPOLY1305_16BIT) fail for other compilers too? Is there a known fix available? (The blog of the author Andrew Moon at https://floodyberry.wordpress.com/ is inactive since 6 years)

Comment: **Note:** The bug has been fixed March 29, 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm a build failure on a pretty vanilla Fedora 22 system:

```
% gcc poly1305-donna.c -c -DPOLY1305_16BIT
% gcc example-poly1305.c -o ex poly1305-donna.o -DPOLY1305_16BIT
% ./ex
poly1305 self test: failed
```

Notice that the test succeeds when I omit `-DPOLY1305_16BIT`.

Also notice:

```
% uname -rmp
4.0.8-300.fc22.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
% gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4)
```

I suggest you submit a bug report.  Andrew has been responsive in the past.

EDIT:

Compiling with clang version 3.5.0 yields the same results as the above gcc test.

Comment: Thank you. I have created an issue at the GitHub site. I know that the 8 bit and 32 bit versions pass the test. 32 or 64 bit is autodetected if no special version is required, therefore I guess you have actually tested the 64 bit version. I will accept your answer, if no other answer with a working  fix will be given.